# Arcpy: Counting number of segments where altitude rises or decreases based on DEM?

Tags: python, dem, 3d-analyst, profile

I have a DEM of Sudety mountains and linear .shp with several hiking paths.

I'm trying solve one problem: How to make a script based on input DEM and input line shapes that would count number of segments of hiking path where the terrain rise is higher than 50 meters or lower than -50 meters and sum these that are >50m to one field and that are <50m to another field.

I was trying to solve this problem with 3D line stack profiles and `arcpy.UpdateRowCursor`, but don't know how to order an iteration that would compare row.HEIGHT with row.HEIGHT of the previous row.

Another question is how to name stack profile's output tables by a field name of particular row?

Comment: What about extracting line vertices elevations and looking for your 50 m change there?

Comment: What exactly is the "rise"? Is it the absolute value of the difference in elevations at the endpoints, or is it perhaps the range of elevations encountered throughout the segment? How do you propose to distinguish a rise of 50 m from a fall of 50 m?

Comment: My answer to this question may help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21211/field-calculatur-in-arcmap-10-how-to-specify-field-row/21230#21230